# Get current top position of document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, offset, scrolltop

I try output something when document scroll top will be equal to offset of some my blocks. But I didn get any results. Here is code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() === 3385) {
        console.log($('#services').offset());
    }
});
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: var top = $('html').offset().top;

Comment: It should be `$(window).scrollTop()`. Also, good luck having a scroll top of exactly `3385` ;) You should probably listening to the scroll event as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('html').offset().top === 3385) {
        console.log($('#services').offset());
    }
});
```